# setState removes an items from an array using filter but removed item stays in state as an empty string

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

In the state of the component I have an array of todo items received from MongoDB via axios. The list in array is rendered using map method into an unsorted list (`<i>` is just an icon in this case):

```
<ul>
  {this.state.items.map(e => (
    <li key={e._id}>
      {e.name}
      <i onClick={() => this.removeItem(e._id)}
      ></i>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

I then need to remove an item using onClick. I'm deleting the item using axios from DB and then filtering the item out of the array in state by the id:

```
removeItem = e => {
  axios
    .delete(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/items/${e}`)
    .then(res => {
      let newItems = this.state.items;
      newItems.filter(item => item._id !== res.data._id);
      this.setState({ items: newItems });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

when I click on the icon in it removes the item from the array. However the `<li>` element of that item remains in DOM with a blanc value.
When inspecting the state I noticed that after the array item is removed the state has an empty string instead of this item (which I guess is then still rendered but without a value.

[Screenshot of the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhR6a.png)

After page refresh it is completely gone. It looks like setState doesn't re-renders the DOM in my case and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Filter method returns a new array, to avoid side effects I would write it this way:

```
...
.then(res => {
   const newItems = this.state.items.filter(item => item._id !== res.data._id)

   this.setState({ items: newItems });
 })
...
```

And to be sure that `state` is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied (as API request may take some time), I suggest:

```
...
.then(res => {
   this.setState(state => {
      return {
         items: state.items.filter(item => item._id !== res.data._id)
       }
   ))
 })
...
```

I am not 100% sure that it is an issue, it would be nice to have a working snippet, but you can try it.